# RewriteRule 301 issue where original URL contains a ? (question mark)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm replacing an existing website so the domain is not changing. I do want to use 301 redirects so that bots and search engines will recognize the new pages. I've tried the following but it did not work.

original URL:
http://example.com/index.php?SiteAction=Directions

new URL:
http://example.com/map/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#301 redirects using RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^index.php?SiteAction=Directions$ http://example.com/map/ [R=301,L]
```

The question mark after the index.php seems to completely break my site like that so I've also tried writing it like this, but nothing happens then:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php(.)SiteAction=Directions$ http://example.com/map/ [R=301,L]
```

I'm using a Dreamhost PS, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot match QUERY_STRING in `RewriteRule`, you need to `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}`.

Use this rule instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^SiteAction=Directions$ [NC]
#301 redirects using RewriteRule
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://example.com/map/? [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you @anubhava that worked perfectly. I did try to read up on how to do this before posting my question. I will now to look up more info on how RewriteCond works.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked out. Good reference is askapache.com for rewrite rules.